# utorrent connectivity: Router drops packets

Tags: router, utorrent, udp

I have some problems downloading via uTorrent 3.4.2 on Win 7 x64.

Symptoms:

- DHT is either *Waiting to log in* or *Nodes (0)*, under Trackers its status is *Waiting for announce...*
- For any torrent, all trackers show *Connection timed out*, all torrents are either *Finding peers* or *Connecting to peers*, but failing.
- Trying to search for an update results in *Unable to contact update server*

Downloading has been working for months without problems, I have not made any changes to the system that I'm aware of.

I'm using a Torguard proxy, disabling it makes no difference, connecting still does not work.

The Windows Firewall has two Inbound rules: UDP In and TCP In (Each set to Allow all connections (incl. NAT) from program C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe, which appears to be the executable running when I start uTorrent), there are no other software firewalls installed.

On the router side, I use an Asus RT-N66U. A firmware update to 3.0.0.4.376_3754 has not helped. On the router side, my logs show a lot (ca. 1500 instances over 12 hours) of the following:

```
Mar  4 13:11:03 kernel: DROP <4>DROPIN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX <1>SRC=BB.BB.BB.BB DST=AA.AA.AA.AA <1>LEN=400 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=21894 PROTO=UDP <1>SPT=500 DPT=500 LEN=380 
Mar  4 13:11:06 kernel: DROP <4>DROPIN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX <1>SRC=BB.BB.BB.BB DST=AA.AA.AA.AA <1>LEN=400 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=21906 PROTO=UDP <1>SPT=500 DPT=500 LEN=380 
Mar  4 13:11:06 kernel: DROP <4>DROPIN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX <1>SRC=BB.BB.BB.BB DST=AA.AA.AA.AA <1>LEN=356 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=21907 PROTO=UDP <1>SPT=500 DPT=500 LEN=336
```

where

```
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is a MAC address, not 100% sure but I think its my routers external interface
AA.AA.AA.AA is my external IP
BB.BB.BB.BB is a source IP
```

I suspect the router is interfering with my uTorrent-connections, but I'm not really sure. Can anyone point me towards next steps? Thank you!

Comment: `SPT=500 DPT=500` doesn't look like BitTorrent traffic; this specific port pair is used by IPSec/ISAKMP tunnels... Have you used an IPSec VPN recently?

Comment: I use a Torguard Socks5 Proxy on Port 1080, uTorrent listening port should be 48958. Otherwise I'm using SSH and RDP to connect to servers, as well as Teamviewer. A recent malware scan was negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the router logs explicitly say packets have been dropped it does point to the router as a possibility. You can directly plug your computer to the external network and bypass the router to double check this.

Most routers have firewalls and other logic to prevent attackers flooding you. Try to disable any firewall or security-like feature of the router to test if that's the case.

On one router I found SPI (stateful packet inspection) to make the router drop packets when torrenting. On another router I found that UDP flood protection mistakenly identified torrent traffic as "flood attack".

If disabling the router security features doesn't work, you can always try adding your torrent-running computer to the DMZ. Depending on the router, that would probably imply setting a static IP for that particular computer. But first make sure that you correctly identify the router as the problem.

Comment: While I'm not 100% positive this was the reason, I've indeed disabled the UDP flood protection on the router, and DHT seems to work 'better' now. 'Better' in quotes as I'm not even sure how to quantify that ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did the other 2 symptoms get any better?

Comment: Usually they are, but if they fail, they fail together. Its really weird, because I have this problems sometimes, sometime not, for a few years now, but I've never been able to reproduce this behavior, even across machines, networks, installations, etc. It might have something to do with the way uTorrent handles Magnet-Links in combination with UDP over a socks5 proxy, but thats as far as I ever got...